# Concatenating two database tables out-of-memory with dplyr

Tags: r, concatenation, dplyr, rbind

I am using `dplyr` to manipulate two tables on a database. I would like to concatenate these two tables out-of-memory / in the database, without needing to download the table data locally. In other words, given two `tbl` objects from a database source:

```
> tbl ( db_src, "db_table_1" )
           a           b           c
1 -0.2246894 -1.48167912 -1.65099363
2  0.5559320 -0.87898575 -0.15634590
3  1.8469466 -0.01487524 -0.53098215
4 -0.6875051  0.23880967  0.01824621
5 -0.6735163  0.75485292  0.44154092


> tbl ( db_src, "db_table_2" )
           a          c
1  0.4287284 -0.3295925
2  0.5201492  0.3341251
3 -2.6355570  1.7916780
4 -1.3645337  1.3642276
5 -0.4954542 -0.6660001
```

i would like to get (in database / out of memory):

```
> tbl ( db_src, "db_table_concatenated" )
           a                   b           c
1  -0.2246894   -1.48167912106676 -1.65099363
2   0.5559320  -0.878985746842256 -0.15634590
3   1.8469466 -0.0148752354840942 -0.53098215
4  -0.6875051   0.238809666690982  0.01824621
5  -0.6735163   0.754852923524198  0.44154092
6   0.4287284                  NA -0.32959248
7   0.5201492                  NA  0.33412510
8  -2.6355570                  NA  1.79167801
9  -1.3645337                  NA  1.36422764
10 -0.4954542                  NA -0.66600006
```

My current implementation uses `dplyr::rbind_list` but this requires the dataframe to be downloaded in memory:

```
# Connecting to database src:
db_src <- src_postgres(dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, user = user,  password = password)

# Load table1 from  database src:
db_tbl_1 <- tbl ( db_src, "db_table_1" )

# Load table2 from  database src:
db_tbl_2 <- tbl ( db_src, "db_table_2" )

#Data to write to the DB: 
db_tbl_concatenated <- rbind_list ( as.data.frame(db_tbl_1, n = -1) , as.data.frame(db_tbl_2, n = -1) ) #In memory / local solution
```

Is there an out-of-memory / in-database solution for this?

Comment: `union(db_tbl_1, db_tbl_2)`

Comment: Thanks, that's the right solution! It works if the src of both `db_tbl_1` and `db_tbl_2` are the same.